# How to remove automated text in function?

Tags: r, function

I am new to functions, and trying to learn

Let us say that I have

```
norm <- function(z){

  n = as.numeric(table(is.na(z))[1])
  m = mean(z, na.rm=T)
  stddev = sd(z, na.rm=T)
  
outdata = data.frame(n=n, 
                     mean=round(m, digits = 1), 
                     sd=round(stddev, digits = 1),
                     median=round(median(z), digits = 1),
                     Q1=round(quantile(z)[2], digits = 1),
                     Q3=round(quantile(z)[4], digits = 1),
                     lower_t.dist=round(m-sqrt(1+(1/n)) * qt(0.975, df=n-1) * stddev, 
                                        digits = 1), 
                     upper_t.dist=round(m+sqrt(1+(1/n)) * qt(0.975, df=n-1) * stddev, 
                                        digits = 1),
                     lower_frac = round(quantile(z, probs = c(0.025)), 
                                        digits = 1),
                     upper_frac = round(quantile(z, probs = c(0.975)),
                                        digits = 1))
return(outdata)
}
```

And then type `norm(iris$Sepal.Length)`

Which gives

```
> norm(iris$Sepal.Length)
      n mean  sd median  Q1  Q3 lower_t.dist upper_t.dist lower_frac upper_frac
25% 150  5.8 0.8    5.8 5.1 6.4          4.2          7.5        4.5        7.7
```

**Question:** why does it automatically print the `25%` on the left side, and how to remove it so its just a blank space?

Comment: You may use `rownames(outdata) <- NULL` in the function but it still gives you a `1` instead of `25%`. Does that suffice?

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: the row names comes from `quantile(z)[2]`

Comment: Yes, thank you, that answered my question and nice solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to see any rownames, not even numbering, you can do

```
norm <- function(z){
  
  n = as.numeric(table(is.na(z))[1])
  m = mean(z, na.rm=T)
  stddev = sd(z, na.rm=T)
  
  outdata = data.frame(n=n, 
                       mean=round(m, digits = 1), 
                       sd=round(stddev, digits = 1),
                       median=round(median(z), digits = 1),
                       Q1=round(quantile(z)[2], digits = 1),
                       Q3=round(quantile(z)[4], digits = 1),
                       lower_t.dist=round(m-sqrt(1+(1/n)) * qt(0.975, df=n-1) * stddev, 
                                          digits = 1), 
                       upper_t.dist=round(m+sqrt(1+(1/n)) * qt(0.975, df=n-1) * stddev, 
                                          digits = 1),
                       lower_frac = round(quantile(z, probs = c(0.025)), 
                                          digits = 1),
                       upper_frac = round(quantile(z, probs = c(0.975)),
                                          digits = 1))
             rownames(outdata) <- rep("", nrow(outdata))
  return(outdata)
}
```

and then you get

```
> norm(iris$Sepal.Length)
   n mean  sd median  Q1  Q3 lower_t.dist upper_t.dist lower_frac upper_frac
 150  5.8 0.8    5.8 5.1 6.4          4.2          7.5        4.5        7.7
```

Comment: Spin-off question. I want to change the name `lower_frac` in outdata to `25%`, but when changing to `"25%" = round(quantile(....` the function prints `X25.`. Do you know how to fix it so it prints ´"25%"` instead of `"lower_frac"` or  `X25.`?

Comment: Edit: No, usually you can do it with `` but I think this might not work here due to the percent sign. I recommend to ask this as a separate question though. There might be workarounds